# Upper bound of probability of not getting all values in independent draws

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

We draw $m$ uniform independent random values among $n$, with $m\ge n$. We consider the probability $p(m,n)$ that not all $n$ values have been drawn. We want an upper bound within a constant factor.

The probability that a given value was not drawn is $q(m,n)=(1-1/n)^m$. If these probabilities were independent, we could use $1-(1-q(m,n))^n$ for $p(m,n)$. However the probabilities are dependent and that expression yields dead wrong values.

How can we rigorously derive an upper bound? I needs not be tight, I'd be happy with something within any constant factor.

---

The question's motivation is to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}p(n\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil,n)=0$, if possible with an explicit upper bound (towards [answering](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/95613/555) an often-asked question about cryptographic hashes reaching their whole stated destination set, under a random oracle model).

This itself is plausible because (as studied in the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Calculating_the_expectation)) the expected number of draws to get all $n$ values is $n(\ln(n)+\gamma)+\frac12+\mathcal O(\frac1n)$, and $n\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil$ grows faster than that, by a factor $\frac1{\ln(2)}>1$.

Comment: Maybe this could help [Example 3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/26.18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Define the indicator variable $X_{ij}=\mathbf{1}[ball ~j ~falls~in~ bin ~i]$ with $Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^m X_{ij}$ the load in bin $i.$ This is a sum of *independent* $X_{ij}$'s.

The expected load of bin $i$ is $\mu=m/n.$ The lower tail of the Chernoff bound is
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y_i\leq (1-\delta)\mu]<
\left(\frac{e^{-\delta}}{(1-\delta)^{(1-\delta)}}\right)^\mu.
$$
Choose $\delta$ such that, say, $(1-\delta)\mu=0.99,$ (i.e., $\delta=1-\frac{0.99}{\mu}$) which means that
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y_i\leq (1-\delta)\mu]=\mathbb{P}[Y_i\leq 0.99]=
\mathbb{P}[Y_i=0]<\left(\frac{e^{-\delta}}{(1-\delta)^{(1-\delta)}}\right)^\mu\quad (*).
$$
Now $m=\lceil \lg n \rceil n,$ or $\mu=\lceil \lg n\rceil$ where $\lg(\cdot)$ is $\log_2(\cdot).$ If my arithmetic is correct, equation $(*)$
becomes essentially
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y_i=0]<
\exp\left(-\mu+0.99-0.99\ln\left(\frac{0.99}{\mu}\right)\right)\leq 
\exp\left(-\mu+0.99\right)
$$
and ignoring the ceiling in $\lg n$ yields a looser upper bound namely
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y_i=0]<\exp\left(-1.4426 \ln n+0.99\right)
$$
and if $n$ is large enough to ignore the $+0.99$ term, we obtain
$$
\mathbb{P}[Y_i=0]<n^{-1.4426}.
$$
Now apply the union bound over the $n$ bins to get
$$
\mathbb{P}[some~bin~empty]=\mathbb{P}[\exists i: Y_i=0]<n^{-0.4426}
$$

---

**Theorem:** (Theorem 5.13 in *Probability and Computing*, Mitzenmacher and Upfal)

*Let $X$ be the number of coupons observed before obtaining one of each of $n$ coupons. Then for any constant $c$*
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[X>n \ln n+ c n]=
1-\exp(-exp(-c)).
$$

Already for $c=5,$ the right hand side is as small as $0.007.$

*Proof outline:* Poisson approximation is correct in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty.$ So assume the number of balls in each bin is a Poisson r.v. with mean $\mu=\ln n+c$ which gives that the probability that a specific bin is empty is
$$
\frac{\exp(-c)}{n}
$$
and since the bin loadings are independent under the Poisson approximation the prob. that no bin is empty is
$$
\left(1-\frac{\exp{-c}}{n}\right)^n \approx \exp(-\exp(-c)).
$$

The proof is delicate and proceeds by splitting the event (where dependence on $n$ is suppressed in the notation)
$$
{\cal E}=\{no~ bin~ is~ empty\}
$$
as
$$
\mathbb{P}({\cal E})=\mathbb{P}({\cal E} ~\cap ~(|X-\mu|\leq \sqrt{2m \ln n}))+
\mathbb{P}({\cal E} ~\cap ~(|X-\mu|> \sqrt{2m \ln n}))\quad (1)
$$
and showing that:

1. $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|> \sqrt{2m \ln n})$ is $o(1).$
2. $\left| \mathbb{P}({\cal E}~|~|X-\mu|\leq \sqrt{2m \ln n})-\mathbb{P}({\cal E}~|~X=m)\right|$ is $o(1).$
3. guarantees that the second term on the right of $(1)$ is $o(1).$
4. guarantees that the difference between the experiment resulting in exactly $\mu$ vs nearly $\mu$ balls makes an asymptotically negligible difference in the probability that every bin has a ball.

**Complements:** Over 99.3 percent of the time the number of coupons required lies in $[n \ln n - 5n, n \ln n+ 5 n]$.

The relationship below may be of interest as well (Theorem 5.7 from the same book) for problems of this type involving balls and bins.

**Theorem:** Let $m$ balls be thrown uniformly independently into $n$ bins. Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a nonnegative function, then
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X_1^{(m)},\ldots,X_n^{(m)}] \leq e \sqrt{m} 
~\mathbb{E}[f(Y_1^{(m)},\ldots,Y_n^{(m)}],
$$
where $X_i^{(m)}$ is the number of balls in the $i^{th}$ bin, for $1\leq i\leq n,$ and where $Y_i^{(m)}$ are i.i.d. Poisson with mean $m/n.$

Comment: posting after midnight, always risky, will see if any typos are there tomorrow

Comment: Bingo. Nice reference

Comment: That's a useful theorem and it does prove $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}p(n\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil,n)=0$. Still the theorem itself does not give an explicit upper bound for $p(n\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil,n)$ for a given $n$. I'm still trying to see if it's proof does.

Comment: @fgrieu, please note that I have in the edit the same answer as in the other answer by robjohn with justification

Answer (score 4):

By the standard urns and balls interpretation, we have $$p(m,n)=1-\frac{n! \, S_{m,n}}{n^m}$$

where $S_{m,n}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. Then the question is equivalent to ask for a lower bound for $S_{m,n}$. There are many, but don't expect something very neat... or practical. [For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Lower_and_upper_bounds). Or [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3007.pdf).

Added: Still not an aswer, but another plausibility argument. The number of balls can be approximated (Poissonization) by $n$ iid Poisson variables with $\lambda=m/n$.
Then the probability that all urns are occupied is

$$ 1-p(m,n)  \approx \left( 1 - \exp(- \lambda)\right)^n$$

If we take $m = a \log(n) n$ and we assume that the approximation is asympotically precise, then for large $n$ we get

$$ 1-p(m,n) \approx \exp(- n^{1-a}) \to \begin{cases} 0 & a<1 \\ 1 & a>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Kudos for the explicit expression of $p(m,n)$, which e.g. yields $p(15,6)=\frac{129\,078\,571}{362\,797\,056}=0.356…$. However the bound $L(n,r)\le S_{n,r}$ with $L(n,r)=\frac1 2(r^2+r+2)r^{n-r-1}-1$ that you linked to, that turns out to be sourced [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(69)80045-1), is extremely loose ($S_{15,6}=420\,693\,273$ vs $L[15,6]=36\,951\,551$) and yields a bound $p(15,6)<0.944$ that's too loose for my taste.

Comment: I suspected that. I added another paper. But I doubt that you'll find a tight useful bound that works for all $m,n$.

Comment: And for your (updated) goal, I suspect that you need an very strict bound! I (wildly) conjecture that the limit is indeed valid for $\log_2$ but not for $\log_3$, for example.

Answer (score 3):

**Approximation of the Probability**

The probability that a particular $j$ values have been missed is
$$
N_j=\overbrace{\quad\binom{n}{j}\quad}^{\substack{\text{number of}\\\text{ways to choose}\\\text{the $j$ missed}}}\overbrace{\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\vphantom{\binom{n}{j}}}^{\substack{\text{probability of}\\\text{missing those}\\\text{$j$ values}}}\tag1
$$
The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion says that the probability of missing at least one value is
$$
p(m,n)=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
p(n\log_2(n),n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}\left(1-\frac jn\right)^{n\log_2(n)}\tag{3a}\\
&\sim\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}e^{-j\log_2(n)}\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&=\left(1-\left(1-e^{-\log_2(n)}\right)^n\right)\tag{3c}\\[9pt]
&=\left(1-\left(1-\tfrac1{n^{1/\hspace{-1pt}\log(2)}}\right)^n\right)\tag{3d}\\[9pt]
&\sim n^{1-1/\hspace{-1pt}\log(2)}\tag{3e}\\[12pt]
&\to0\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(3b)}$: Poisson approximation
$\text{(3c)}$: Binomial Theorem
$\text{(3d)}$: $e^{-\log_2(n)}=\frac1{n^{1/\hspace{-1pt}\log(2)}}$
$\text{(3e)}$: Binomial approximation
$\text{(3f)}$: $1-1/\log(2)\approx-0.442695$

---

**Comparison of Values**
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n&p(n\log_2(n),n)&n^{1-1/\hspace{-1pt}\log(2)}\\\hline
10&0.275663&0.360832\\
100&0.118840&0.130200\\
1000&0.045682&0.046980\\
10000&0.016798&0.016952
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The approximations used here are over-approximations, and I am working on showing that in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: Even if the (upper) bound of $p(m,n)$ is only for $m\approx\log_2(n)$, that seems the closest to what I'm asking, and enough for my goal.